# BitmapImage to Base64 in Windows Phone 8.1

Tags: c#, windows-phone, base64, windows-phone-8.1, bitmapimage

I am writing a Windows Phone 8.1 app (WINRT).

I picked a photo using **FileOpenPicker**. How to convert this **BitmapImage to Base64**?

or any other solution like BitmapImage to image to memorystream to byte and finally to base64?

My current method is giving me "AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA" only:

```
 private void ConvertImageToBase64(BitmapImage BitmapImageObject)
        {
            byte[] bytearrayObject = null;

            MemoryStream MemoryStreamObject = new MemoryStream();
            WriteableBitmap WriteableBitmapObject = new WriteableBitmap(BitmapImageObject.DecodePixelWidth, BitmapImageObject.DecodePixelHeight);
            Stream StreamObject = WriteableBitmapObject.PixelBuffer.AsStream();
            StreamObject.CopyTo(MemoryStreamObject);
            bytearrayObject = MemoryStreamObject.ToArray();
            finalBase64 = Convert.ToBase64String(bytearrayObject);          

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You are converting an empty buffer: Your WriteableBitmap doesn't have any data in it. Even if you did, that's probably not what you want. You generally want to encode the bitmap file format (png, jpg, etc.) rather than the raw pixels. That is what you get from the file picker before decoding it into a BitmapImage. Just open the StorageFile, get its data stream, and call ToBase64String on it.